# Odd scrolling lag issue across multiple browsers - two windows open/video streaming

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, video, chromium, scrolling

I believe I've narrowed this down to the specific browser that is streaming the video (youtube etc.), having a second window/process of that browser affects scrolling performance. 
However, when using a different browser the issue does not occur.

Troubleshooting steps:

Scenario 1: Two Firefox windows open with video playing in one window... scrolling through another webpage on the second window is very laggy - pausing the video clears up the lag.

Scenario 2: Firefox still playing video but this time using Chrome as the second window to test the same site - the lag issue does not happen, nice and smooth.

Scenario 3: Switch to Chrome as the video player and Firefox as the scroll tester... Firefox also does not lag. (proving it's not browser specific)

Scenario 4: Testing Chromium, Firefox and Chrome - all do the exact same thing: if a second window/process of that browser is opened, it is severely affected by streaming video (making scrolling stuttery/laggy) but if a different browser is used in conjunction, both perform smoothly.

Has anyone seen this issue before?

Comment: I have a similar issue with Firefox, but it's only a problem if I have Firefox windows spread scross multiple workspaces: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1341026/extreme-graphical-lag-when-firefox-windows-are-spread-across-multiple-workspaces

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score -1):

I'm experiencing something similar. When I open a second Firefox windows even typing any URL there is laggy.