# Extreme graphical lag when Firefox windows are spread across multiple workspaces

Tags: nvidia, firefox, intel-graphics, workspaces, nouveau

If I have Firefox windows spread across multiple workspaces, it causes extreme graphical lag and slowness. Moving them to the same workspace instantly fixes the issue. Does anyone know why this would be the case?

I have a dual screen monitor, an i7-4770 with 16GB RAM and GeForce GTX 750 Ti [nouveau drivers], and Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS (5.4.0-73-generic), and the Unity Desktop.

This issue does *not* occur on other Ubuntu systems (again with the Unity desktop) I own.

**Edit:** Requested `screenfetch` output:

``````
                          ./+o+-       username@PC_NAME
                  yyyyy- -yyyyyy+      OS: Ubuntu 20.04 focal
               ://+//////-yyyyyyo      Kernel: x86_64 Linux 5.4.0-88-generic
           .++ .:/++++++/-.+sss/`      Uptime: 22h 20m
         .:++o:  /++++++++/:--:/-      Packages: 2941
        o:+o+:++.`..```.-/oo+++++/     Shell: bash 5.0.17
       .:+o:+o/.          `+sssoo+/    Resolution: 3840x1080
  .++/+:+oo+o:`             /sssooo.   DE: Unity 7.5.0
 /+++//+:`oo+o               /::--:.   WM: Compiz
 \+/+o+++`o++o               ++////.   WM Theme: Arc-Dark
  .++.o+++oo+:`             /dddhhh.   GTK Theme: Yaru-dark [GTK2/3]
       .+.o+oo:.          `oddhhhh+    Icon Theme: ubuntu-mono-dark
        \+.++o+o``-````.:ohdhhhhh+     Font: Ubuntu 12
         `:o+++ `ohhhhhhhhyo++os:      Disk: 1.2T / 2.0T (63%)
           .o:`.syhhhhhhh/.oo++o`      CPU: Intel Core i7-4770 @ 8x 3.9GHz [37.0°C]
               /osyyyyyyo++ooo+++/     GPU: NV117
                   ````` +oo+++o\:     RAM: 4749MiB / 15855MiB
                          `oo++.
``````

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: Nope, @J.Schmidt. Still looking for a solution. It's really annoying me,  but I'm stumped as to what to try next - hence asking this question :-/

Comment: After opening firefox on multiple workspace , can you please tell the output of screenfetch as a screenshot, If not installed
 then install it , It is a useful tool.

Comment: Does this issue occur only in firefox or everything lags out

Comment: Also why do you open firefox on different workspaces ( maybe there would be some specific work ) , But i suggest you to use new tabs instead of whole new workspaces , cause workspaces require more ram then normal.

Comment: Also Do you use swap or are there any useless processes going in background ? Just close all them you can use a tool called stacer to optimise your desktop

Comment: Also I would recommend using xfce4 desktop if you want to do heavy usage ( firefox is heavy )

Comment: @AkshajSingla: It's only Firefox. No other programs exhibit this behaviour. And I do have many tabs, but in this particular instance I want to use multiple workspaces. No, I'm not switching to XFCE.

Comment: Please post output of ```screenfetch``` **when firefox starts lagging .**

Comment: If not installed then install it

Answer (score 2):

I found an answer after having tested multiple changes in `about:config` I hope I narrowed it down correctly:

Open a new tab and go to `about:config`, search for `gfx.webrender.software` and set it to `true`.

You may need to restart your Firefox/computer for it to take effect.

Comment: this worked for me! On EndevourOS